# Angular-Calendar no carga datos hasta dar click

Tags: angular, calendar

estoy llamando a una api para que me traiga la fecha de algunas citas medicas

```
nInit(): void {

   this.CitesService.getAllCites().subscribe(
     (r:any)=>{
      this.ListadoCitas = r.table; //acá recibo la data
      this.ListadoCitas.forEach(element => {  //acá pusheo la data para mostrarla
       this.events.push({
         start: new Date(element.fecha!),
         end: new Date(element.fecha!),
         title: element.observacion,
         color: colors.blue,
       })
      });
     },
     e=>{
       console.log(e);
     }
   )
       this.loadData++;
  }
```

y carga el calendario perfecto : https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM9fp.jpg

Pero no me carga la data hasta click en cualquier otra parte del calendario (por ejemplo el día 5 o al boton de siguiente): https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEPBH.jpg

Comment: Como tienes el html??

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/bNLnE2QeBs9qp37e4tqmNP